# How to make 3-dot icon visible on any background?

Tags: style

There is a file manager in my application. Hovering the files shows a 3-dot icon at the top-right corner. The problem is, that it is difficult to make it visible enough on different backgrounds, since the icons and thumbnails can be of different color.

I came up with adding dark background for 3-dots and making 3-dots white. So now it's visible on any background, but I honestly don't really like the solution.

What are other ways to make 3-dot icon visible on different backgrounds?

[image]

Comment: I would likely say to create a 3 dots image in a defined color with 50% opacity or something like that, but it's not easy to find a solution...Personally I like the one you provided at the moment, and I think it's a good solution

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me. Maybe try out the design with the ellipsis in black and the background in white. A dark border around the square, or a subtle drop shadow would help it standout more on light backgrounds

Comment: Sadly one one can be accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem this way:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe if you add a border / stroke might work.
[image]

Comment: Agreed - it's what we do on food packaging when we cannot control the final background (multiple products, different images, retailer input) e.g. white dots black key line - on a light backdrop the key line will save it and on a dark backdrop key line will disappear and the white dots will work.

Answer (score 2):

How about inverting the underlying image by the shape? This would have the advantage of working with many colors

[image]

Or perhaps for some very complicated imagery you could inverse the blurred image, inverse average and so on.:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a method for creating that 'inverse + average' example?

Comment: Sure what platform do you use @JoryO ?

Comment: @joojaa 'Inverse+Blur' method is really interesting. I'd like to play around with it. How can it be implemented?